# C - Missing 0 in hexadecimal output

Tags: c, hex, byte

I had to test if my machine is using the little or the big endian. For this reason i wrote this code. I can see that my machine is using the little endian. But i dont know why the output from my first byte is only D. Should it not be 0D?

```
union int2byte
{
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    unsigned int hex;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    union int2byte hexby;

    hexby.hex = 0xBAADF00D;

    printf("%u\n",hexby.hex);
    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < 4; counter = counter + 1)
    {
        printf("Hex for Byte %u is %X.\n",counter+1, hexby.bytes[counter]); 
    }

}

Output:
3131961357
Hex for Byte 1 is D.
Hex for Byte 2 is F0.
Hex for Byte 3 is AD.
Hex for Byte 4 is BA.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%X` does not output leading zeros.  Use `%02X` instead.  The `2` tells it to output at least 2 digits, and the `0` tells it to pad the output on the left side with a `'0'` character if the output is less than 2 digits.

Comment: You can also use `%.2X` and the C99 Rationale recommends using that instead of `%02X`, but many people ignore what the Rationale says (so `%02X` is probably more common than `%.2X`).